# On route change data disappears, how to persist data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-typescript

In my application, I am listing `pokemon` from backend. after the pokemons listed in the `pokemon-list` component, on click on any of the pokemon i am trying to show the details of the same.

But the whole data is disapears suddenly on click of `view details` button. unable to undestand the correct approach to implement the `redux` store. any one guide me to get the proper way to implement the same?

I required:

1. on page load, all `pokemons` need to listed in the list component
2. on click of view details like to show the individual `pokemon`
3. when click on view-list again, need to show the `pokemons` as like page load, without any backend call.

please help me. I am new to redux and react. looking for the correct way to fix the issues.

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-thunk-oirm66?file=/src/components/pokemon.module.tsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forge to pass the reset of the properties with reducer. when the view details requested, list of user missed, since i did not pass the previous states. it works for me:

```
const pokemonReducer = (state = initialState, action: PokemonDispatchTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POKEMON_FAIL:
      return { loading: false };
    case POKEMON_LOADING:
      return { loading: true };
    case POKERMON_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, pokemons: action.payload };
    case POKEMON_DETAILS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, showPokemon: action.payload };//mistake is here
    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called redux-persist

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Try it out it will help you store whatever you want

Comment: Parent component is ideal, how data clears?

Comment: normally! is creared from the state if you leave that component. So I thing the behavior is narmal!. Maybe what you need is to find a way you can keep it there. use cookies, localstorage or a persist gate to keep it there! an create an action for the user to delete them when they want.

Comment: I have added the live demo, please play with it if you like..